# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.AudioManager.setVibrateSetting(int, int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am trying to use toggle button.
**Below is the code:**

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Activity2() {
        super();
    }
    AudioManager audio; 
    @Nullable

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity2, container, false);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    }

    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
      //audio  =new AudioManager();

        // Is the toggle on?
        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

        if (on) {
            // Enable vibrate
            audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,
                    AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
            audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
                    AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
        } else {
            // Disable vibrate
            audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,
                    AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
            audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
                    AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
        }
    }

}
```

**And here is the xml:**

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOn="Vibrate on"
        android:textOff="Vibrate off"
        android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>
```

I am trying to use toggle button and it is giving me error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.media.AudioManager.setVibrateSetting(int, int)' on a null
>   object reference.

Please Help...Thanks!

Comment: you have your AudioManager initialization commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You forgot to initialize your **`AudioManager`** and **`ToggleButton`**

You need to initialize your **`AudioManager`** and **`ToggleButton`** in **`onCreate()`**

```
ToggleButton ToggleButton;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);  
        audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  
        ToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
 }
```